# Getting "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value" error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to make a register page, but when I try to register I get the error above. The code:

```
DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', first_name, last_name, password, email)', array(':first_name'=>$first_name, ':last_name'=>$last_name, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email));
```

Comment: Correct your placeholders. `first_name`, `last_name`, `password` and `email` are different than `:first_name`, `:last_name`, `:password` and `:email`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: Any Solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040543/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value-any-solution)

Answer (score -2):

The problem seems to be due to this part: `\'\'`. All you need - to remove it, cause id field is autoincremental.

Just leave:

`DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (first_name, last_name, password, email)', array(':first_name'=>$first_name, ':last_name'=>$last_name, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email));`

Comment: If I remove \'\' I get this error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list